# Dynamic vanity redirects using custom module or plugin (Retour)?

Tags: redirect, category, plugin-retour

I'm needing a set of redirects that are created dynamically using Categories. I currently have a Category Group and inside of that group I have categories that can be nested 3 levels deep, producing URIs like: `/first-category/second-category/third-category`. Also of note, each category has its own template.

Here's the use case:

A visitor goes to the following URL:

`https://www.somedomain.com/third-category`

but, it is redirected to the actual full URL:

`https://www.somedomain.com/first-category/second-category/third-category`

I'm currently using the Retour plugin, but can't quite figure out how to create the redirects dynamically. There are a lot of categories so creating explicit redirects for each category is a bit cumbersome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retour [provides some events](https://nystudio107.com/docs/retour/advanced.html#resolve-redirect-events) that you can hook into to provide custom redirect logic. In this case, `Redirects::EVENT_AFTER_RESOLVE_REDIRECT` is the most suitable event to use. Register an event hook in a custom module like this:

```php
use nystudio107\retour\services\Redirects;
use yii\base\Event;

// init()
Event::on(
    Redirects::class,
    Redirects::EVENT_AFTER_RESOLVE_REDIRECT,
    $this->resolveCustomRedirects(...),
);
```

In the callback, you can check if a category for the slug in the path exists and set the `redirectDestUrl` to that categories' URL:

```php
use nystudio107\retour\events\ResolveRedirectEvent;
use craft\elements\Category;

public function resolveCustomRedirects(ResolveRedirectEvent $e)
{
    $path = $e->pathOnly;

    if (preg_match('%^/([\w\d-]+)/?$%', $path, $matches)) {
        $categorySlug = $matches[1];
        $matchingCategory = Category::find()->slug($categorySlug)->one();
        if ($matchingCategory) {
            $e->redirectDestUrl = $matchingCategory->getUrl();
        }
    }
}
```

The regex might need some work, but you get the general idea. See the linked documentation page for details.

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly what I needed. Perfect for a jumping off point. Thank you @MoritzLost!

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature request that some people have asked for in Retour: a way to allow authors to easily create "short URLs" to entries.

I take it that you'd be interested in this as well?

That said, you can accomplish what you want with Retour right now -- it throws events that a custom module could listen for, and do whatever it wants in terms of redirects:

https://nystudio107.com/docs/retour/advanced.html#redirect-events

Comment: Yes, "short URLs" is the ultimate goal, and not just for Categories in my instance but for any entry/category/asset with a lengthy URI. Awesome, thanks @andrew.welch for the speedy reply!